# How to delay android repeating notification start

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I am using this code to start notification that will repeat every 3 days:

```
 public void setNotification() {
        boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 10000,
                new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);

        if (!alarmUp) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 21);

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
            int ALARM1_ID = 10000;
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    this, ALARM1_ID, myIntent, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            assert alarmManager != null;
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 3, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
```

Everything looks good but I want my notification to start 1 day after first starting the application and calling this function. I thought that calendar.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY part in:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 3, pendingIntent);
```

is responsible for the first start. But it looks like it is not. Even though I set it to start after 1 day, notification shows up to user immediately after calling this function.
Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setInexactRepeating()` instead of `setRepeating()`. When you use `setInexactRepeating()`, Android synchronizes repeating alarms from multiple apps and fires them at the same time.

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 3, pendingIntent);
```

Note that:

**ELAPSED_REALTIME**: Fires the pending intent based on the amount of time since the device was booted, but doesn't wake up the device. The elapsed time includes any time during which the device was asleep.

**RTC_WAKEUP**: Wakes up the device to fire the pending intent at the specified time.

Comment: Doesn't work. This way notification doesn't start at all